# duplicate entries in JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've this JSON:
[image: JSON]

I don't want this duplicates, I can I fix my code?

```
 let caratteristiche = html.match(/<table width="100%">(.*?)<\/table>/mi);

if (caratteristiche) {
    for (let el of caratteristiche) {
        let element = el.match(/<span class="OD_(red|blue)">(.*?)<\/span><\/td>/mig)

        if (element && element.length > 0) {
            // <span class="OD_blue">Climatizzazione</span></td>
            // <span class="OD_blue">Impianti Gas</span></td>
            for (let elem of element) {
                try {
                    let item = elem.match(/<span class="OD_(red|blue)">(.*?)<\/span><\/td>/i);
                    obj.caratteristiche.push(item[2])
                } catch (e) {
                    //
                }
            }
        } else {
            obj.caratteristiche = null
        }
    }
}
```

this is my **caratteristiche**:

> Array(2) [<…an="2"
> class="OD_last_row_red">, <td class="OD_ba…td colspan="2"
> class="OD_last_row_red">, 1335, <img class="OD_img_omb…an="2"
> class="OD_last_row_red">, undefined]

and this element that i cycle on it to scrape only text between html tags

> Array(6) [Climatizzazione, Impianti Gas, Installazione Ganci traino, Navigatori Autoradio, Pre-revisioni, Consegna a domicilio]

[image: element]

Comment: No images of code. Instead use snippets.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways of removing duplicates in arrays.

```
let chars = ['A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'B'];
let uniqueChars = [...new Set(chars)];
```

or

```
let uniqueChars = chars.filter((c, index) => {
    return chars.indexOf(c) === index;
});
```

Comment: Nice trick with `Set`, man! I did not knew about this.